# name attribute is not working in add/remove input field dynamically function

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

**html**

```
<div class="field_wrapper">   
    <div>
        <input id="size" type="text" name="size[]" value="" placeholder="Size" style="width:120px;" required="" />
        <input id="sku" name="sku[]" type="text" value="" placeholder="SKU" style="width:120px;" required="" />
        <input id="price" type="numver" name="price[]" value="" placeholder="Price" style="width:120px;" required="" />
        <input id="stock" type="number" name="stock[]" value="" placeholder="Stock" style="width:120px;" required="" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">add</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var maxField = 10;
    var addButton = $('.add_button');
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
    var fieldHTML = '<div><br><input type="text" name="size[]" style="width:120px" placeholder="Size"/>   <input type="text" name="sku[]" style="width:120px" placeholder="SKU"/>   <input type="text" name="price[]" style="width:120px" placeholder="Price"/>   <input type="text" name="stock[]" style="width:120px"  placeholder="Stock"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">remove</a></div>';
    var x = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
        }
    }); 
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
```

the issue is that name attribute was working only for first field after adding multi fields then name attribue array was not work for multi fields please help me to sove this error

Answer (score 1):

You are over-writing the same element onto the page.  Thus, any previous `size[]` or `sku[]` or whatever, is going to be removed in favor of the over-written elements.

You can get around this by specifying the exact name within the array. Something like this on the initially loaded page:

```
<input id="size" type="text" name="size[1]" value="" placeholder="Size" style="width:120px;" required="" />
```

and then in your JS, use your var `x` value inside the array (start at 2 though):

```
var fieldHTML ='';
var x = 2;
$(addButton).click(function(){
    if(x < maxField){ 
        x++;
        fieldHTML = '<div><br><input type="text" name="size['+x+']" style="width:120px" placeholder="Size"/>   <input type="text" name="sku['+x+']" style="width:120px" placeholder="SKU"/>   <input type="text" name="price['+x+']" style="width:120px" placeholder="Price"/>   <input type="text" name="stock['+x+']" style="width:120px"  placeholder="Stock"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">remove</a></div>';
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
    }
});
```

You will have to update the `fieldHTML` var *inside* your click function to accept the variable within the array as `x` increments each time.

Comment: sir I wrote exact same code with the same entries which you edit but still not worked. it only picked the first entry     [size] => Array
        (
            [1] => h
        )

    [sku] => Array
        (
            [1] => w
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
        )

    [stock] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )
this is the output

Comment: @ Watercayman```
var maxField = 10;
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); 
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');   var fieldHTML ='';
var x = 2;
$(addButton).click(function(){
    if(x < maxField){ 
        x++;
 fieldHTML = '<div><br><input type="text" name="size['+x+']" style="width:120px" placeholder="Size"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">remove</a></div>';
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
    }
});
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    }); ```

Comment: OK, so we know from the output that the code is correctly adding the array on the page with index since it starts at 1 and not 0.  This means the code in the answer is correct.  But, it looks like the page is not seeing the whole array when sending.  How are you sending the form data back to the controller?  If through JS, you'll need to make sure it is seeing the dynamically loaded content (`$(document)....`) rather than looking at the static page content, which would only have 1 set of your inputs.

Comment: When you add a set with the button, if it correctly adds a new set of inputs, the JS code is working correctly.  The issue must be on whatever is sending the content not seeing the dynamically added code.  This is a secondary failure, but now that you have the appended text that is no longer over-writing, you can solve this by adding the `$(document)` scope for the code sending the form data to grab the newly added form elements.

Comment: i send form data back to controller through php  `<form role="form" method="post" @if(empty($project_data['id']))action="{{url('admin/add_edit_project_data')}}" @else action="{{url('admin/add_edit_project_data/'.$project_data['id'])}}" @endif name="project_data" id="project_data" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf`
this form contains 7 input fields, 2 select list and 3 check box all were working fine but not this field              `Route::match(['get','post'],'add_edit_project_data/{id?}','ProjectDataController@add_edit_pro_data');`

Comment: `public function add_edit_pro_data(Request $req, $id = null){ if ($req->isMethod('post')) {
             $data = $req->all();
             echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;` this is my code in controller `$(document).ready(function(){ ....javascript code});` here i used `$(document)...` in javascript code as i mentioned before

Comment: OK, are you adding the new inputs *inside* the existing form?  If so, this should work.  If you are and it isn't working, you can test sending the form via a dynamic JS send.  This shouldn't be necessary, but if you serialize the form and send via an ajax method, you can test to see if all goes through.  Also - in your controller, `dd()` the `$request` object.  On the HTML page, view the DYNAMIC source, make sure everything is added correctly from the JS.  I think you've got something else going on that is causing the error, as this should have worked for you.  Test as above to see.